# MongoDB Hadoop streaming adapter

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

Trying to make use of your post:
https://gist.github.com/2884606

I try to run the command:

hadoop jar mongo-hadoop-streaming-assembly*.jar -mapper mapper.rb -reducer reducer.rb -inputURI mongodb://127.0.0.1/twitter.in -outputURI mongodb://127.0.0.1/twitter.out

Get the following errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.MongoStreamJob

I compiled jar mongo-hadoop-streaming-assembly*.jar but it does not contain the above class.

I tried to use -libjar to include archive of classes but hadoop is not recognizing it.

Also tried to export CLASS_PATH to include above.

Used following to build the Hadoop Streaming  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/streaming

./sbt mongo-hadoop-streaming/assembly

Comment: Hadoop 1.0.3
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1335192
Compiled by hortonfo on Tue May  8 20:37:40 UTC 2012
From source with checksum e6b0c1e23dcf76907c5fecb4b832f3be

Comment: build.sbt looks like follows:

Comment: name := "mongo-hadoop"

organization := "org.mongodb"


hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "default"

Comment: did you run ./sbt package to build the adapter?

Comment: did you solved this problem? I'm getting same error and tried with Hadoop 0.23, 1.1.2 and 1.21. All versions get same error.

Answer (score 3):

Apache Hadoop 1.0.3 does not support streaming.  The Apache Hadoop versioning scheme is rather confusing, as 1.0.x is actually based off an older version (0.20) than the current dev branch (0.23) which will become Apache Hadoop 2.0 (!).

For more information on supported Hadoop versions and limitations, see [Building the Adapter: Streaming Support](http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/Building+the+Adapter.html#Streaming+Support).

An easier Hadoop version to get started with is [Cloudera Release 3](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH+Downloads), which has package downloads as well as prebuilt VMs available.